# Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers

Tags: python

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)?

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

N=9 
# your set of numbers
nums = np.array([2,7,11,15])

# prepare list of all possible combinations of two numbers using built-in generator
combs = [i for i in combinations(nums,2)]

# sum up these two numbers
sums = np.sum(combs, axis=1)

# find index of wanted summed of the two numbers in sums
good_comb = np.where(sums==N)[0][0]

# search the indices in your original list, knowing index in combs
indices_sum_to_N = [np.where(nums==i)[0][0] for i in combs[good_comb]]
```

print(indices_sum_to_N)

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate to grab the indexes that match the criteria you need. The answer below is just a brute force solution using enumerate. It will return a list of lists. Please note that the index comparison is to just go over the items above diagonal and not have duplicates (e.g. if [1,2] is in result [2,1] will not be).

```
result = []

for index1, value1 in enumerate(items):
    for index2, value2 in enumerate(items):
          if index1>index2 and (value1 + value2)==target:
              result.append([index1, index2])

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this brute force method which returns the values and indexes as a dictionary?

```
import itertools

def get_indexs_of_sum(search_list, search_val):  

    #remove any values higher than the search val
    search_list = [val for val in search_list if val <= search_val]

    #get all combinations with 2 elements    
    combinations = list(itertools.combinations(search_list, 2))

    #check which lines sum the search val
    totals = [comb for comb in combinations if sum(comb) == search_val]

    #get indexes of answers
    answerDict = {}

    #loop answers get indexes and store in a dictionary
    for i,answer in enumerate(totals):
        indexes = []
        for list_item in answer:
            indexes.append(search_list.index(list_item))

        answerDict[i] = {"Values":answer,"Index":indexes}

    return answerDict



#GET THE LIST AND THE SEARCH VALUE

search_list = [19,15,1,13,1,3,16,7,11,10,16, 12, 18, 3, 15, 18, 7, 17, 6, 1, 2, 17, 1, 4, 12, 2, 14, 8, 10, 9, 19, 1, 18, 2, 3, 18, 3, 6, 6, 9]    
search_val = 21
    
#call the function
answers = get_indexs_of_sum(search_list, search_val)
```

And the output

```
{0: {'Values': (19, 2), 'Index': [0, 20]},
 1: {'Values': (19, 2), 'Index': [0, 20]},
 2: {'Values': (19, 2), 'Index': [0, 20]},
 3: {'Values': (15, 6), 'Index': [1, 18]},
 4: {'Values': (15, 6), 'Index': [1, 18]},
 5: {'Values': (15, 6), 'Index': [1, 18]},
 6: {'Values': (13, 8), 'Index': [3, 27]},
 7: {'Values': (3, 18), 'Index': [5, 12]},
 8: {'Values': (3, 18), 'Index': [5, 12]},
 9: {'Values': (3, 18), 'Index': [5, 12]},
 10: {'Values': (3, 18), 'Index': [5, 12]},
 11: {'Values': (7, 14), 'Index': [7, 26]},
 12: {'Values': (11, 10), 'Index': [8, 9]},
 13: {'Values': (11, 10), 'Index': [8, 9]},
 14: {'Values': (12, 9), 'Index': [11, 29]},
 15: {'Values': (12, 9), 'Index': [11, 29]},
 16: {'Values': (18, 3), 'Index': [12, 5]},
 17: {'Values': (18, 3), 'Index': [12, 5]},
 18: {'Values': (18, 3), 'Index': [12, 5]},
 19: {'Values': (3, 18), 'Index': [5, 12]},
 20: {'Values': (3, 18), 'Index': [5, 12]},
 21: {'Values': (3, 18), 'Index': [5, 12]},
 22: {'Values': (15, 6), 'Index': [1, 18]},
 23: {'Values': (15, 6), 'Index': [1, 18]},
 24: {'Values': (15, 6), 'Index': [1, 18]},
 25: {'Values': (18, 3), 'Index': [12, 5]},
 26: {'Values': (18, 3), 'Index': [12, 5]},
 27: {'Values': (7, 14), 'Index': [7, 26]},
 28: {'Values': (17, 4), 'Index': [17, 23]},
 29: {'Values': (2, 19), 'Index': [20, 0]},
 30: {'Values': (17, 4), 'Index': [17, 23]},
 31: {'Values': (12, 9), 'Index': [11, 29]},
 32: {'Values': (12, 9), 'Index': [11, 29]},
 33: {'Values': (2, 19), 'Index': [20, 0]},
 34: {'Values': (19, 2), 'Index': [0, 20]},
 35: {'Values': (18, 3), 'Index': [12, 5]},
 36: {'Values': (18, 3), 'Index': [12, 5]},
 37: {'Values': (3, 18), 'Index': [5, 12]},
 38: {'Values': (18, 3), 'Index': [12, 5]}}
```

Or without itertools:

```
def get_indexs_of_sum_no_itertools(search_list, search_val):  
    answers = []
    #loop list once
    for i,x in enumerate(search_list):
        #loop list twice
        for ii,y in enumerate(search_list):
            #if indexes aren't dupes and value matches:
            if x != y and x + y == search_val:
                answers.append({"indexes":(i,ii),"values":(x,y)})
    return answers

search_list = [19,15,1,13,1,3,16,7,11,10,16, 12, 18, 3, 15, 18, 7, 17, 6, 1, 2, 17, 1, 4, 12, 2, 14, 8, 10, 9, 19, 1, 18, 2, 3, 18, 3, 6, 6, 9]
search_val = 14

ans = get_indexs_of_sum_no_itertools(search_list,search_val)
```